# Django Allauth how to change username=first_name?

Tags: django, django-allauth

When using django allauth for social account registration allauth defines the username automatically as first_name grabed from 3rdparty. So, for example: if facebooks John Cucumber registers he gets username "john". I would like to change this to "john cucumber". Use both his first and last name as username. Didn't see anything about this in docs.

Thanks

**EDIT :** Some more explanation:

1. *Anonymity is not default*
   I am trying to achieve that as default the users are not anonymous (using nicknames). They have the ability to change username to nick, but only after fully registered, by default they use full name from social network.
2. *Registration is quick (no forms)*
   I also want to have them registered and login quickly (that is why I am using social network login in the first place, one click and you are a user of my page). So, I don't wanto bother users with registration forms. As pointed out in Andrew's post below the
   current setup of allauth causes many names conflicts (there can be only one John all others need to change they username). There will be less conflicts with full names than with first names. But this is something I go after later, once this issue is solved.

Comment: As far as I can see in the documentation there is this:
`ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED`
Which:
`The user is required to enter a username when signing up. Note that the user will be asked to do so even if ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD is set to email. Set to False when you do not wish to prompt the user to enter a username.`

Comment: I know about this but I want the user to have a username. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Allauth has a extract_common_fields method, maybe you could use that and override the save in the db (maybe using a pre_save signal), sorry haven't used allauth so I am not familiar if there is a function to override the user creation.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be a short matter of time before your users start seeing conflicts with the generated usernames. As soon as you have more than one "John Smith" then you'll have a problem.

Also, many users may prefer not to have their full name as their username.

Personally, I always use email for the login, never usernames, but if you're adamant about it, I'd recommend that you show a form allowing the choice of username and giving the default as `"%s %s" % (first_name, last_name)`  or similar.

To ensure the form is displayed, edit settings:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False  # require social accounts to use the signup form
```

From the [documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> [If true] Attempt to bypass the signup form by using fields (e.g. username,
>   email) retrieved from the social account provider. If a conflict
>   arises due to a duplicate e-mail address the signup form will still
>   kick in.

You should be able to use a hook to supply the suggested username before the form is rendered.

A working example* of django-allauth with Twitter Bootstrap is at https://github.com/aellerton/demo-allauth-bootstrap. However, it does *not* use usernames but it does show the signup form after social signup.

*Disclaimer: I wrote the example.

Comment: Andrew thanks for the effort, I've been thinking also about this alternative, but it is not what I want. I don't want to show any registration form for username, the social account register losses sense for me if the user has to input everything. Also, anonymity should be optional not default on that page, so default full name as username and change if the user is uncomfotable.